# ImportError DLL load failed while importing fasttext_corpusfile

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

When I try to import gensim, I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\fasttext.py", line 264, in <module>
    from gensim.models.fasttext_corpusfile import train_epoch_sg, train_epoch_cbow
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing fasttext_corpusfile: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, utils  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .fasttext import FastText  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\fasttext.py", line 266, in <module>
    raise utils.NO_CYTHON
RuntimeError: Compiled extensions are unavailable. If you've installed from a package, ask the package maintainer to include compiled extensions. If you're building Gensim from source yourself, install Cython and a C compiler, and then run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` to retry.
```

My computer is Windows Server 2022 Data Center, python is 3.8.10, gensim is 4.2.0.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your help.

I re-installed gensim (gensim-4.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl) from https://pypi.org/project/gensim/#files, but still had the above problem.

Comment: How specifically did you install Gensim? Are you using a project-specific virtual environment – either Python3's built-in `venv` tools, or alternatively something configured & managed by the `conda` tool – as is often a best practice? On a system where Python & major libraries are well-supported, usually something as simple as "pip install gensim" will work – or at least provide useful error messages on installation. Were there any messages describing installation failures in your installation method?

Comment: I didn‘t use project-specific virtual environment. I installed gensim using "pip install gensim" without any errors. However, when I try to import gensim, it cann’t work.

Comment: It does not sound like you originally installed Python via a simple `pip install gensim`, because (1) in general, someone who uses such a simple usual installation won't even know what `.whl` file is used, and you for some reason mentioned `gensim-4.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`; (2) that `.whl` file is likely built specifically for CPython 3.9 - the `cp39` in its name – while elsewhere you mention that you're using Python 3.8.10. It's pretty hard, if not impossible, for a simple `pip install gensim` to pick the wrong-version installation files.

Comment: I suggest uninstalling anything you've done so far, & starting from scratch, & then creating, installing-into, & then specifically using a project-specific virtual-environment. It's a best-practice that protects your system's default Python, & helps make it clear conscious choice which version of Python, & which set of library installs, are used. &, while built-in `venv` functionality works fine, `conda` also works well, with good online instructions, & pays extra attention to Windows support. You could start with miniconda via instructions at: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Comment: If that start-over & use-an-explicit-environment doesn't help on OS "Windows Server 2022 Data Center", and you have freedom to choose another operating system, you might also want to consider switching to a Linux-based OS. As mush of Python & the related data-science libraries are mostly developed, tested, & used on Linux-based systems, often things "just work" on the 1st try there, without requiring extra debugging as comes up more often on Windows-based OSes.